Must an invertible square matrix $V$ with $V^\dagger V = I$ or $V V^\dagger = I$ be normal or unitary?
Let $V$ be an invertible square matrix, and consider the following two conditions:

$V^\dagger V = I$ (orthonormal columns), or
$V V^\dagger = I$ (orthonormal rows).

My questions are:

Must $V$ necessarily be normal (i.e., satisfy $V^\dagger V = VV^\dagger$) under either of these conditions?
Does either condition imply that $V$ is unitary (i.e., satisfy both $V^\dagger V = I$ and $V V^\dagger = I$)?


For square matrices, left invertibility is equivalent to invertibility (same as right invertibility). See If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$ for proof. Meaning that if you show for square matrices $A,B$ that $AB = I$, then both are invertible and $B = A^{-1}$.
So even the assumption "Let $V$ be an invertible square matrix" is superficial, since either of the orthonormal columns/rows assumptions leads to $V$ being unitary (and thus normal).

The two conditions you give are equivalent. To see this, first note that we may multiply the equation for condition 1 by $V^{-1}$ on the right to obtain $V^\dagger = V^{-1}$. Multiplying the equation for condition 2 by $V^{-1}$ on the left yields the same result. Because either condition can be rearranged to yield the equation $V^\dagger = V^{-1}$, they must be equivalent.
It then follows that if a matrix satisfies these conditions, it must be normal as $V^\dagger V = I = V V^\dagger$, and it must be unitary because both conditions hold.
